# Making long-to-wide transformation by grouping/seperating rows by a delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I need to make a long-to-wide transformation (see image below) using [**Pandas**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zaje.png).

[image]

I made this code but unfortunately, it does not work !

##### Code :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': ['Id001', 'Id001', 'Id002', 'Id003', 'Id003', 'Id003'],
 'val1': [np.nan, 'B', 3, 'H', np.nan, 'J'],
 'val2': ['N', np.nan, 'M', 2, 'K', 'I'],
 'val3': [5, 'E', 'P', 'L', np.nan, 'R']})

df = df.groupby('Id')
             .agg(
              val1=('val1',' | '.join),
              val2=('val2',' | '.join),
              val3=('val3',' | '.join))
             .rename_axis(None))

df
```

Here is the error I'm getting :

##### Error :

> **TypeError**: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Do you have any suggestions/solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the presence of `NaN` values, `NaN` values are categroized as floating point types and hence you can't join strings with `NaN`. The solution is to explicitly cast the NaN's to string

```
df.filter(like='val').astype(str).groupby(df['Id']).agg('|'.join)
```

---

```
          val1   val2     val3
Id                            
Id001    nan|B  N|nan      5|E
Id002        3      M        P
Id003  H|nan|J  2|K|I  L|nan|R
```

Comment: I have a last question. In case that the columns `val1`, `val2` and `val3` have not a pattern name, what do I have to change in your code, please ? In the dataset I'm working on, these three columns are named : `Reference`, `Type` and `Model`.

Comment: In that case you can select the required columns then cast to string and do aggregation: `df[['Refrerence', 'Type', 'Model']].astype(str).groupby(df['Id']).agg('|'.join)`